# How to use defaults write hexa values with -data on OS X?

Tags: macos, command-line-interface

I'm playing with some "defaults write" for [my dotfiles](https://github.com/MoOx/dotfiles) & can found a way to write hexa values.

When I do a read I get something like this

```
$ defaults read com.ragingmenace.MenuMeters CPUSystemColor
<040b7374 7265616d 74797065 6481e803 84014084 8484074e 53436f6c 6f720084 84084e53 4f626a65 63740085 84016301 84046666 6666831b 677c3f00 83d70ea8 3d0186>
```

So I tried this commands without success (after checking the `man defaults`)

```
$ defaults write com.ragingmenace.MenuMeters CPUSystemColor -data "<040b7374 7265616d 74797065 6481e803 84014084 8484074e 53436f6c 6f720084 84084e53 4f626a65 63740085 84016301 84046666 66668364 79783f83 1b677c3f 83bf8073 3f0186>"
Command line interface to a user's defaults.
Syntax:

'defaults' [-currentHost | -host <hostname>] followed by one of the following:

    read                                 shows all defaults
    read <domain>                        shows defaults for given domain
    read <domain> <key>                  shows defaults for given domain, key

    read-type <domain> <key>             shows the type for the given domain, key

    write <domain> <domain_rep>          writes domain (overwrites existing)
    write <domain> <key> <value>         writes key for domain

    rename <domain> <old_key> <new_key>  renames old_key to new_key

    delete <domain>                      deletes domain
    delete <domain> <key>                deletes key in domain

    import <domain> <path to plist>      writes the plist at path to domain
    import <domain> -                    writes a plist from stdin to domain
    export <domain> <path to plist>      saves domain as a binary plist to path
    export <domain> -                    writes domain as an xml plist to stdout
    domains                              lists all domains
    find <word>                          lists all entries containing word
    help                                 print this help

<domain> is ( <domain_name> | -app <application_name> | -globalDomain )
                or a path to a file omitting the '.plist' extension

<value> is one of:
    <value_rep>
    -string <string_value>
    -data <hex_digits>
    -int[eger] <integer_value>
    -float  <floating-point_value>
    -bool[ean] (true | false | yes | no)
    -date <date_rep>
    -array <value1> <value2> ...
    -array-add <value1> <value2> ...
    -dict <key1> <value1> <key2> <value2> ...
    -dict-add <key1> <value1> ...
```

You can see that the format seems unrecognized.
So some variation without success

```
$ defaults write com.ragingmenace.MenuMeters CPUSystemColor -data <040b73747265616d747970656481e803840140848484074e53436f6c6f72008484084e534f626a656374008584016301840466666666836479783f831b677c3f83bf80733f0186>
# same error as the first one

$ defaults write com.ragingmenace.MenuMeters CPUSystemColor -data "<040b73747265616d747970656481e803840140848484074e53436f6c6f72008484084e534f626a656374008584016301840466666666836479783f831b677c3f83bf80733f0186>"
# same error as the first one

$ defaults write com.ragingmenace.MenuMeters CPUSystemColor -data <040b7374 7265616d 74797065 6481e803 84014084 8484074e 53436f6c 6f720084 84084e53 4f626a65 63740085 84016301 84046666 66668364 79783f83 1b677c3f 83bf8073 3f0186>
zsh: parse error near `\n'

$ defaults write com.ragingmenace.MenuMeters CPUSystemColor -data <'040b7374 7265616d 74797065 6481e803 84014084 8484074e 53436f6c 6f720084 84084e53 4f626a65 63740085 84016301 84046666 66668364 79783f83 1b677c3f 83bf8073 3f0186'>
zsh: parse error near `\n'
```

Any idea how to get this working ?

Answer (score 2):

It's really simple, just remove `<`, `>` & all spaces.

```
$ defaults write com.ragingmenace.MenuMeters CPUSystemColor -data "040b73747265616d747970656481e803840140848484074e53436f6c6f72008484084e534f626a656374008584016301840466666666836479783f831b677c3f83bf80733f0186"
```

You can verify it's working by doing a `defaults read`

```
$ defaults read com.ragingmenace.MenuMeters CPUSystemColor
```

<040b7374 7265616d 74797065 6481e803 84014084 8484074e 53436f6c 6f720084 84084e53 4f626a65 63740085 84016301 84046666 6666831b 677c3f00 83d70ea8 3d0186>

Comment: What if I have to use the `-array-add` argument too? With which I add an xml string in one command?